# Can I use React Navigation Version 3?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

In my earlier project, I used React navigation version 2, We are developing a new project, Can I use React Navigation version 3 ?

Comment: I don't see why not. It also has some nice new features added.

Comment: It's not even in their changelog yet, and has multiple issues opened on their github.. I'd rather wait for bugs to be fixed in a minor/patch version...